# Pandas Dataframe not updating in for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to flip random bits in a pandas dataframe with 1 million rows and 8 columns containing only zeros and ones. However after implementing it using a for loop, I noticed that it does not update my dataframe. I have tried using loc, iloc, at, iat and none of them is giving me results. I also tried flipping the bits using if...else condition, and xor, and neither attempts yielded results. I also tried working with numpy arrays, that did not work also. What do I do?
Here is my code that performs the bit flipping:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
data_in = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
data = data_in
for i in range(0, 10):
    a = random.randint(0, 999999)
    b = random.randint(0, 7)
    b = str(b)
    #using xor
    data.at[a, b] = data.at[a, b] ^ 1
    #using if condition
    # if (data.loc[a, b] == 1):
    #     data.loc[a, b] = 0
    #     print('t')
    # else:
    #     data.loc[a, b] = 1
    #     print('f')
Here is the code I use to check how many bit flipped, which always turns out to be zero:
c = abs(data_in-data)
c = c.sum(axis=0)
c = c.sum()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top, you are setting data equal to data in. This will default be by reference. So when you change data, you are *also* changing data_in, so the two dataframes are the same when you compare them later. Try explicitly copying to get a *copy* of the dataframe instead of a *reference*

`data = data_in.copy()`